# Shell output to text file

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have the following shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ )) 
do
    printf in_port=$i,actions=
    for (( j = 1 ; j <= 6; j++ ))
    do
        if [ $i != $j ]; then   
                printf output:$j,
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Which, produces the following output:

```
home@mininet:~$ ./hostsScript.sh
in_port=1,actions=output:2,output:3,output:4,output:5,output:6,
in_port=2,actions=output:1,output:3,output:4,output:5,output:6,
in_port=3,actions=output:1,output:2,output:4,output:5,output:6,
in_port=4,actions=output:1,output:2,output:3,output:5,output:6,
in_port=5,actions=output:1,output:2,output:3,output:4,output:6,
in_port=6,actions=output:1,output:2,output:3,output:4,output:5,
```

How would I go about appending each line of this output to a txt file, line-by-line?

Comment: `command > output_file`

Comment: Or `command >> output_file` for the next lines (1 > overwrites the file, >> appends to the file).

Comment: Or `( command1; command2 ) > output_file`.

Comment: `{ command1; command2; } > output_file` would be better yet.

Comment: Actually, neither parentheses are needed after the loop: `for ... do; done > output_file` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1 inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ )) 
do
    printf in_port=$i,actions=
    for (( j = 1 ; j <= 6; j++ ))
    do
        if [ $i != $j ]; then   
                printf output:$j,
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
done >> output_file
```

option 2 inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >> output_file

for (( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ )) 
do
    printf in_port=$i,actions=
    for (( j = 1 ; j <= 6; j++ ))
    do
        if [ $i != $j ]; then   
                printf output:$j,
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

option 3 in run command:

```
./hostsScript.sh >> output_file
```